# How to preview using execcommand in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, text-editor, wysiwyg

I am using TinyMCE jquery plugin in my project. It works fine. I am trying to use exec command to view the preview. It is not working.

```
<a href="javascript:;"onclick="$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('Preview');">Preview</a>
```

But the same command for bold works fine.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the right command. Try

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('mcePreview');
```

Comment: i see tinyMCE.execCommand has three parameters whether we want to display the ui or not.. i have 1 plugin created but i don't wont to display it and.. this parameter thing is not working .. can u help ..??

Comment: i need some more information of what you did and what you tried. idealy create a new question - this will yield more attention and you will be able to style your code

Comment: in an all i want to use execCommand('mcePreview') but don't want to show the popup i want that process done in background and after completion reflect tinymce with contents

Comment: this will not work as you may have expected - open up a new SO thread and define what you did and want there